# add unbounded_Strings to enum ada

Tags: string, enums, ada

I am quite new to programming and Ada I have to say so I don't know if this an easy thing to do or so, I tried googling and searching this site but I can't really find it!

I want to add an array of strings to an enum (or enum_def don't know exactly what it is)

First i had

```
name_type is (name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, etc)
```

and I did my things with this that worked

But now I want to fill this name_type (so without anything in it, maybe 1 starting name) with an array of unbounded_strings, so I add the unbounded_strings one by one.

So the thing would be like :

```
name_type is ()
ustring_array is array (1 .. 50) of Unbounded_String;

for I in 1 .. 8 loop
    ustring_array (I) := "Get_Name"  --  i get this name from somewhere
end loop;

fill name_type with strings from ustring_array (not code, I don't know how to do this part )
```

so the ustring_array would look something like ("name1", "name2", "name3", etc)
and i want the name_type to look like (name1, name2, name3, etc) so that they are individual pieces but not strings

so that the size of my name_type is defined by the number of strings in ustring_array

Is this possible or am I asking for the impossible?

Comment: If I understand your question, then you're asking the impossible.  When you declare an enumeration type, the identifier names have to be defined in your program.  You can't define them at runtime.  Whatever it is you want, it's probably not an enumeration type.

Comment: Thanks, it is not really needed, would just have made my life a bit easier! But I was still curious if it was possible. I wanted to add an array of names to a dropdown box and we have a function that works on an enum type but not on an unbounded_Strings array but it just took me a bit more work now!

Still thanks for the answer!

Comment: Tell whoever wrote that function that it was a bad idea to make it so inflexible.

Answer (score 0):

If you read [the part](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05aarm/html/AA-A-10-10.html) that is connected to IO with Enumeration types in the [ARM](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05aarm/html/AA-TOC.html), you will find more or less the answer.

There is also a solution using the Image attribute as described [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Types/Enumeration).

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.  It is just a couple of links with no additional content, which does not meet the standards for a StackOverflow answer.  Not to mention that the links probably do not answer the OP's question at all, although they're somewhat related.

Comment: Thanks, but I found out its not possible ye what I wanted to do!

Comment: @ajb the question was far from clear and I just understood it wrong. I first tought it was a student question which explains why I didn't want to provide a full answer.
Your comment made me understand what was the goal. 

Sorry for the noisy answer.

Comment: @FrédéricPraca If you want to just provide a link to get someone to do their own research, it's still best to do it as a comment.  I've made dozens of comments like that.  And yes, this wasn't the clearest question I've ever seen.

Comment: @ajb Thanks for the advice I'll follow it

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like, essentially, you are asking about extending enumerations. That's not possible, but it is possible to define an array that maps an enumeration to an Unbounded_String:

```
Type Directions is (Up, Down, Left, Right);


-- Assuming "+" renames of the string to unbounded string.
Direction_Text : Constant Array (Directions) of Unbounded_String :=
( Up => +"Upwards",
  Down => +"Downwards",
  Left => +"Port",
  Right => +"Starboard"
);
```

There's also a new container `Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Holders` which could be used as an element in the array to hold unconstrained-length strings.